# Read data from bluetooth - Android, Raspberry Pi Zero, Bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have an application in Android which connects with my Raspberry Pi Zero via Bluetooth. 
I start connection in my phone and I only confirm a pairing in RPI.

I send a data from my Android to RPi and I know, this data is received in RPi because when I use:

```
sudo hcidump -a hci0
```

I see this [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exkWv.png)

But I don't have idea how  can I write a programm (in python for example) which will read this data and run of led or something else with GPIO.

I tried pybluez.service but I have only:

```
Waiting for connection on channel 2
```

I tried

```
sudo rfcomm watch hci0
```

but I have:

```
"Can't bind RFCOMM socket : Address already in use
```

And others,I tried the first 5-10 tutorials in google or youtube and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth error "Can't bind RFCOMM socket: Address already in use": means that the `bind()` function used by the command producing the error (in your case, `rfcomm`) failed because there is another local socket with the same number (in your case, referred to channel 2) already bound by a local application.

A way to solve this problem is to find the local application in your system which is currently binding that socket (maybe another instance of `rfcomm` on the same channel). Close the socket in that application, or simply terminate it.